# Is public void main(String[] args) Invalid java main method signature ?

Tags: java, static

I compiled the following code through notepad

```
class MainClass{
  public void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hello!");

  }
}
```

I didn't use static keyword and the above code executed, but when I did

```
javap MainClass
```

in the command prompt,I got the following output,

```
class MainClass {
MainClass();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

the keyword was added itself, so is

```
public void main(String args[])
```

also considered a valid signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [JLS Sec 12.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method main must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of `String`.

---

I think you might have been looking at an out-of-date version of the class; when I tried decompiling your code, `static` has not been added.

```
Compiled from "MainClass.java"
class MainClass {
  MainClass();
  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: when i use javap -verbose MainClass | find "version"  my class version comes out to be minor version: 0 major version: 52. Is it different in your case then?

Comment: The fact that you're compiling for Java 8 isn't relevant: these requirements on the main method have long been true. When I say "out of date version" I mean that you are looking at the class file for a version of your code when it included the `static` keyword.